# How can I locate an odor emanating from the kitchen/laundry area?

Tags: plumbing

I live in South Florida.  My home is a one level, 2400-sq ft, u-shaped with bedrooms on one side and kitchen/laundry on the other side.  I have a consistent odor but it's not constant.  It comes and goes and is isolated to the kitchen area.  My laundry room is adjacent to the kitchen, so my wife seems to think that the odor is more prevalent when she does laundry.  I haven't made that connection.  I have called in several plumbers for their thoughts and nothing was resolved.  One plumber found a small leaky pipe under the sink and repaired it, but that was not the solution.  Is there a specialist in "odor detection" who could diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you describe it? Does it smell like sewer gasses (methane, poop, etc.).  Do you hear any gurgling or notice any bubbles when you flush toilets?  Do you know where your drain vents are on your roof? Are they close to any open windows, intake vents, etc?

Comment: If you had a leak, mold and/or mildew could be the culprit.

Comment: I had a similar problem in our laundry area.  Running an empty load on hot water with bleach cleared the issue up. Also have you tried pouring white vinegar down your disposal to see if that helped?

Comment: Verify you have a p-trap under your kitchen sink. If you have a garbage disposer fill the sink with ice, run hot water over it with the disposer on, and use a bamboo utensil or something to carefully force the ice into the disposer. It wouldn't hurt to poor some bleach done it as well while your doing this. Check the baseboards in the kitchen and in the laundry room. There may be a leak in the wall that you can't see but they generally warp/bow the baseboards after a while. My washer's drain line has a p-trap in the wall. Yours may not.

Comment: Do you have a front loading clothes washer?  Those are notorious for smelling moldy.  A monthly bleaching is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> **How can I locate an odor...?**

Don't underestimate the detection abilities of your nose!  Get on your hands and knees, and stick your nose right into every nook and cranny.  Closing your eyes will help make your nose seem more sensitive.  Smell along edges, cracks, baseboards, pipe cutouts, switch plates, jambs, sills, light fixtures, drains, and anywhere there's a gap or mating of any kind.  Pull out the frig, dishwasher, washing machine, dryer, or remove their base plates and check underneath with a flashlight.  Check the washer drain hose and drain pipe.  Pull out all drawers in case something fell inside the cabinets.  Don't forget outside walls too.  Check any attic or basement or crawlspace.  Cover every inch, and sooner or later you'll zero in on where the smell is definitely strongest.  The source can't be far away.